# How-to Publish a Windows Phone 7 Project on Codeplex

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, codeplex, oneclick

I used SVN tools and CodePlex repository for developing Windows Phone 7 Application. How do i create a OneClick Release for the project so that others can download and work on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the download tab, for your project, click on the "Create New release" link. This will allow you to create a simple easy way for you to create a version of the project that's easy to download.

If you want the latest version of the source, then in the "Source Code" tab there is a link to get the latest vresion of the code.

If you want a way for other people to contribute code back to the project then you'll need to add them to the project (via the People tab).